# How to read data events (chunks) from node.js request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm having trouble with something very basic. Going through node.js in Action (great book so far!) and I can't get this simple example to work. Perhaps it's because the stream api was updated after the book came out. I'm not sure. Anyway, here's the code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log("Chuck: ", chunk);
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log("End of Request");
    res.end('yay');
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

The console.log('Chunk: ', chunk) never fires. It's almost as if the data events never fire, but according to the documentation the presence of the data handler should switch the readable stream (req) into flowing mode. Am I missing something?

Any help would rock!

Comment: Ahaha, no request body. Never mind : ) cURLing works. For example: curl http://localhost:3000 -d "{'bam': 'check it'}"

Comment: could you show us the client-side code? How do you send a request to your server? The `data` event will fire only if there is something inside the body of the request. For instance, a simple GET request has only headers, no body.

Comment: You know how sometimes when you ask for help with a math problem, the act of verbally explaining the problem leads to the answer? And then even though the person from whom you asked help still doesn't quite understand your math problem, you have a eureka dance going on?

Comment: I believe [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is relevant ;-)

Comment: Use body in the request body of the request

Answer (score 1):

The above code is current initally the request body is undefined you have to pass request data inorder to execute this line.

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log("Chuck: ", chunk);
  });
```

**Use postman to send data in the request this line will be executed**